# Changing Document headers with Javascript or equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm running into the following issue

For the most part, the whole website is generated on the initial load, so there is no changing of pages and new content fades in nicely using Javascript, however there is a portion of my website that is a bit load intensive, and that is the calendar (lots of events read from database to the calendar), so I use a GET/POST request to change months and so on, so now whenever someone refreshes the page it will say the general "Are you sure you want to resubmit blah...ect", the client doesn't want this even though there's no reason for the user to refresh.  Is there a way to change headers so when I click a link it will change headers and get rid of that request?

Comment: I don't see how "*headers*" has to do with any of that. Now, I can't see how this may happen if you are using AJAX in the first place. Are you sure that you are applying the right method?

Comment: show your code that generates `Are you sure you want to` message... seems highly unorthodox

Comment: @charlietfl it's a post request causing the error on refresh..

Comment: assumed you meant you were using ajax to get data...last comment is very confusing. Do you mean page submits by form post? If so get rid of that and use AJAX